# When is a type equal (template specialization)?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, using

I store a configuration as a type:

```
using CONFIG1 = Config<x, y, z>;
using CONFIG2 = Config<a, b, c>;
using CONFIG3 = Config<x, y, z>;
```

For each config, there's a class template specialization, which does some more configuration work:

```
template <class CONFIG>
MyClass;

template <>
MyClass<CONFIG1>{...}

template <>
MyClass<CONFIG2>{...}

template <>
MyClass<CONFIG3>{...}
```

Now, as you see, `CONFIG1` happens to have the same definition as `CONFIG3`.

The question is:

1. Which specialization will be taken for `CONFIG1` and `CONFIG3`, or: **When is a type equal?** Is it it's name or it's actual content?
2. If it's the actual content, how can I achieve that `CONFIG1` and `CONFIG3` actually invoke different specializations?

Comment: I expect this code to not compile, precisely because `CONFIG1` is the same as `CONFIG3`. The compiler will likely complain that you can't specialize twice for the same type. You shouldn't be able to define two distinct specializations in the first place, let alone invoke them.

Comment: I also expect this behavior, but it does not answer the question.

Comment: Does it really not answer your question, or does it merely not tell you what you wanted to hear? `CONFIG1` and `CONFIG3` are two names for the same type - isn't that what you were asking? If you want distinct specializations, you would have to make them distinct types, not typedefs for the same type. E.g. you could make them classes derived from `Config<x, y, z>`.

Comment: If you're compiler doesn't give an error here (at least at template instanciation) you should write a bug report.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CONFIG1` and `CONFIG3` are the same type, therefore your specialization will fail with

```
error: redefinition of 'struct MyClass<Config<x, y, z> >'
struct MyClass<CONFIG3>{};
```

You can use inheritance to create a new type:

```
using CONFIG1 = Config<x, y, z>;
struct CONFIG3 : CONFIG1{};
```

Live example: https://ideone.com/4GrlaW

Answer (score 2):

CONFIG1 and CONFIG3 are the same type. If you doubt, you can verify with `std::is_same`

Answer (score 1):

`CONFIG1` and `CONFIG2` are different template instantiations, `CONFIG1` and `CONFIG3` are not (supposed `a`,`b`,`c` are all different from `x`,`y`,`z`).

> 1. Which specialization will be taken for `CONFIG1` and `CONFIG3`, or: When is a type equal? Is it it's name or it's actual content?

`CONFIG1` and `CONFIG3` are equal types. Naming by `typedef` is irrelevant.

> 2. If it's the actual content, how can I achieve that `CONFIG1` and `CONFIG3` actually invoke different specializations?

You cannot, `typedef` just provides aliases not actually new types.

Use an (empty) publicly inherited class, to actually create a new type.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Rewritten my answer a bit.